# Find a time invariant differential equation that $C(t) = C_0 (fe^{-at} + (1-f)e^{-bt})$ solves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How do you write the time invariant differential equation for $C(t) = C_0 (fe^{-at} + (1-f)e^{-bt})$?

As per my understanding, a practical way to quickly identify a time invariant differential equation (DE) is to check for the an explicit presence of the time variable. If it is absent in the equation, then the system that the DE represents is a time invariant system.

An example of such a system is $$\frac{dC}{dt}=-kC(t)$$ which we can solve to get $$C(t) = C_0 e^{-kt}$$ where $$C_0 = C(t)|_{t=0}$$ Now I have the system $$C(t) = C_0 (fe^{-at}+(1-f)e^{-bt} )$$ I would like to know if this system can be transformed into a time invariant differential equation.

There are two additional caveats. In my system of interest, $C_0$ is not known and hence cannot appear in the DE. However I do welcome any solution with $C_0$ as a first step in the direction.

Secondly, a second order DE is also probably not going to work because I would need $\frac{dC}{dt}|_{t=0}$, which is also not known.

Comment: The linear system with unknown $(x,y,z)$ $$\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcr} C(t)z &=& C_0fx&+&C_0(1-f)y \\ -C'(t)z &=& aC_0fx&+&bC_0(1-f)y\\ C''(t)z &=& a^2C_0fx&+&b^2C_0(1-f)y \end{array}\right.$$ must have the nonzero solution $$(x,y,z)=(e^{-at},e^{-bt},1)$$ hence the associated determinant must be zero, that is, $$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}C(t)&C_0f&C_0(1-f)\\ -C'(t)&aC_0f&bC_0(1-f)\\ C''(t)&a^2C_0f&b^2C_0(1-f)\end{array}\right|=0$$ or, more simply, $$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}C(t)&1&1\\ -C'(t)&a&b\\ C''(t)&a^2&b^2\end{array}\right|=0$$ that is, $$(a-b)C''(t)+(a^2-b^2)C'(t)+(a^2b-ab^2)C(t)=0$$ ...

Comment: ... and, assuming that $a\ne b$, $$C''(t)+(a+b)C'(t)+abC(t)=0$$ More simply, $-a$ and $-b$ must be the roots of the associated characteristic polynomial.